# Eclipse Markers without IResource/IFile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to use markers in eclipse without having an IResource/IFile?  It doesn't look like IFileSystem or IStorage/IEditorInput support having markers.  It seems like there must be a way to do this, but I don't see it.

What I'm doing is opening files from a remote system.

Comment: I think you are correct, it's impossible. All of markers in Eclipse reference IResource.

Comment: @KoheiMikami that would be a bummer.  So non workspace files treated as second class citizens?

Comment: How are you opening the remote files?  Why markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers are part of the Workspace code and are always on `IResource` and derived interfaces (`IFile`, ...).

Non-workspace files are very much second class citizens in Eclipse.

You can use `IFile.createLink` to create links in the workspace to non-workspace files.

Comment: It appears this is the correct answer.  I've done further research and no alternative has turned up.