# Marker for IStorage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an editor plugin where I am using IStorage as editor input. I want to push errors of my editor content to eclipse default Problems View, for which I need to write markers.

I am very much aware of the fact that markers can be created on IResource only and not on IStorage.

I don't want my editor to be associated with a file or any other resource.

Can anyone suggest any manipulative way to implement marker on IStorage ?
Or may be any way to not associate a resource with editor but using IResource ?

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: The Problems View finds the markers it displays by looking at resources, that is all it looks at.

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks for the reply. So the markers are always associated with a Resource , right ? can't we do it for IStorage instead of IResource ?

Comment: I saw your reply on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854135/eclipse-markers-without-iresource-ifile?rq=1

but couldn't reply on this due to stack overflow restrictions. 
you were pointing towards something IFile.createLink

Comment: They are always IResource. Even if they weren't the Problems View only looks at resources.

Comment: Okay Greg, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already understood, there is no way to have a Marker on anything that's not an IResource. What I would suggest as workaround if you want to take advantage of markers (and more) is that you create a dummy IProject in your workspace, and that you create a "linked resource" for the file under this IProject rather than opening directly it as a IStorage.

Using an IFile linking to your file will allow you take advantage of markers, search, change history and many other IDE features that are only available for IResources.